# Simulating a login attempt with incorrect password in an RSpec controller spec raises BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, bcrypt-ruby

The SessionController spec for an app I'm working on currently looks like this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe SessionController do
  let(:user) { create(:user, phone_verified: true, email_verified: true) }

  describe "POST #create" do
    context "with valid username and password" do
      before do
        post :create, user: { username: user.username, password: user.password }
      end
      specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(dashboard_path) }
      specify { expect(session[:user_id]).to eq(user.id) }
    end

    context "with invalid username" do
      before do
        post :create, user: { username: "doesntexist", password: user.password }
      end
      specify { expect(response).to render_template(“login”) }
      specify { expect(session[:user_id]).to be_nil }
    end

    context "with invalid password" do
      before do
        post :create, user: { username: user.username, password: "badpassword" }
      end
      specify { expect(response).to render_template(“login”) }
      specify { expect(session[:user_id]).to be_nil }
    end
  end
end
```

The first two context blocks work exactly as expected. The examples in the third context block fail:

```
2) SessionController POST #create with invalid password
     Failure/Error: post :create, user: { username: user.username, password: "badpassword" }
     BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash:
       invalid hash
```

From what I've been able to find out on StackOverflow and by looking at the bcrypt-ruby source code, this means the password digest stored in the database is invalid. Since all three blocks are using the same `let` block to create the user, I'm at a loss as to why this would happen with an incorrect password and not a correct one. It also works normally when I start up `rails s` and try to log in through the view. Does anyone have any idea what is happening?

We're using the built-in has_secure_password method, and we're not using devise or any other authentication-related gems.

Comment: Are you creating the same `:user` twice, once in the `let` and then subsequently in each test?  Perhaps you should build the user in the `let` since you are creating for each test.

Comment: The `:create` method in this case is trying to create a session, not a user. Also, I forgot to mention: I'm using database_cleaner around each example, so the examples shouldn't be interacting with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the database fixed this problem, although it's still not clear to me what caused it or why it only happened under such specific circumstances.